# Ler apenas uma linha no arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo

Quero que o fgets,pegue apenas uma linha e não o arquivo inteiro,como eu faço isso em C? Se eu imprimir a variável palavra na função ela imprime tudo e também gostaria de retornar essa linha na main.[image: problema]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<string.h>

int abrir_arquivo(char *palavra){
    FILE *file;

    file=fopen("Frutas forca.txt", "r");
    //se o arquivo for encontrado

    if(file==NULL){
        printf("erro");
    }
    while((fgets(palavra,50,file))!=NULL)
        printf("%s",palavra);

    fclose(file);

}

int main(){
    char palavraforca[50];
    abrir_arquivo(&palavraforca);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O `fgets` já faz isso, ele lê até o *buffer* atingir o tamanho especificado ou encontrar o final da linha ou final do arquivo. Se não está fazendo isso, tem outra coisa errada. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e elaborar um [mcve] incluindo um exemplo do texto que está lendo?

Comment: Pronto, editado

Comment: Só faltou o [mcve] e o exemplo do texto lido.

Comment: Pronto, editado

Comment: Sua função abrir_arquivo espera receber um array de caracteres (isto é seu endereço)  mas você a está invocando informando como parâmetro o endereço do endereço do array. Troque abrir_arquivo(&palavraforca); por abrir_arquivo(palavraforca);

Comment: continua nao printando na main

Comment: Por algum motivo,quando não coloco pra printar na função,a função main consegue printar o arquivo,porem so a primeira linha.

Comment: Você consegue explicar o que `while((fgets(palavra,50,file))!=NULL)` faz?

Comment: Ela pega uma linha do arquivo 'file' e adiciona na variável 'palavra' com tamanho 50,enquanto for diferente de null que significa vazio,enquanto tiver caractere ele vai pegar e adicionar na variável palavra

Comment: Posso esta errado na definição do null mas creio que seja isso

Answer (score 1):

Acho melhor usar o fscanf.

Bem, para arquivos de texto, existem duas funções especialmente para pegar dados de dentro do arquivo (fscanf()) e para colocar dados dentro de um arquivo (fprintf()).

A estrutura do fscanf() é: fscanf(arquivo, "tipo de dado", variável).

Onde:

arquivo: é o ponteiro para o arquivo definido com FILE;

tipo de dado: é como o scanf normal (%s para string, %d para inteiro, etc)

variável: é a variável que vai guardar o valor lido do arquivo (obrigatóriamente igual ao tipo de dado passado e com "&" antes da variável, exceto para strings).

A estrutura do fprintf() é: fprintf(arquivo, "tipo de dado\n", variável).

Onde:

arquivo: é o ponteiro para o arquivo definido com FILE;

tipo de dado: é como o printf normal (%s para string, %d para inteiro, etc, e aqui faz-se necessário o "\n" caso você queira pular uma linha de texto).

variável: é a variável que vai guardar o valor lido do arquivo (obrigatóriamente igual ao tipo de dado passado).

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int abrirArquivo(char *palavra); //define apenas o cabeçalho da função. Sem o cabeçalho, a função deve ficar acima do main


int main(){
    char palavraforca[50];

    abrirArquivo(palavraforca);
    printf("%s\n", palavraforca);

    return 0;
}


int abrirArquivo(char *palavra){
    FILE *file;
    if((file=fopen("Frutas forca.txt", "r"))==NULL){ //poupa linha atribuindo e comparando ao mesmo tempo
        printf("ERROR: abrirArquivo fopen == NULL\n"); //informa onde e qual foi o erro
        exit(1); //para o programa nesse ponto.
    }

    fscanf(file, "%s", palavra); //lê uma linha, caso queira mais linhas, use while(!feof(file))

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

No seu caso, você deve querer pegar uma linha específica, talvez essa nem seja a melhor forma de implementar, mas ai vai um código que pega uma linha específica do arquivo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int abrirArquivo(char *palavra, int linha); //define apenas o cabeçalho da função. Sem o cabeçalho, a função deve ficar acima do main


int main(){
    char palavraforca[50];
    int linha;

    linha=1; //para pegar a palavra na primeira linha
    abrirArquivo(palavraforca, linha);
    printf("Linha 1: %s\n", palavraforca);

    linha=2; //para pegar a palavra na segunda linha
    abrirArquivo(palavraforca, linha);
    printf("Linha 2: %s\n", palavraforca);

    linha=3; //para pegar a palavra na terceira linha
    abrirArquivo(palavraforca, linha);
    printf("Linha 3: %s\n", palavraforca);

    return 0;
}


int abrirArquivo(char *palavra, int linha){
    FILE *file;
    if((file=fopen("Frutas forca.txt", "r"))==NULL){ //poupa linha atribuindo e comparando ao mesmo tempo
        printf("ERROR: abrirArquivo fopen == NULL\n"); //informa onde e qual foi o erro
        exit(1); //para o programa nesse ponto.
    }

    /*
    define cont como 0 linhas, a partir da hora que é lida a primeira linha, cont fica com 1 e 
    caso queira pegar a linha 1 o laço é parado, pois cont agora é igual a linha
    */
    int cont=0;
    while(cont!=linha){
        fscanf(file, "%s", palavra); //lê uma linha
        cont++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Qualquer dúvida a mais é só perguntar. Boa sorte e bons estudos.